# Have Trouble Understanding OCaml Code

Tags: ocaml

I need to modify an OCaml function:

```
let removeDuplicates l = 
  let rec helper (seen,rest) = 
      match rest with 
        [] -> seen
      | h::t -> 
        let seen' = failwith "to be written" in
        let rest' = failwith "to be written" in 
      helper (seen',rest') 
  in
      List.rev (helper ([],l));;
```

The function needs to take a list l and return the list with all duplicates removed.  The `failwith "to be written"` parts is where I'm supposed to write my code.  I understand how the helper function works but am having trouble understanding this part helper `(seen',rest')`. I'm not exactly sure how the function is supposed to flow with this part or how it works when you include a bunch of `in`'s all together. We are allowed to use `List.rev` which reverses a list and `list.mem` which returns true if a certain element is in a list.  Can someone please explain to me how the flow of the function is supposed to work so I can start to write a solution.

Answer (score 1):

That line is confusing because it's indented incorrectly, or so I would claim. The proper indentation looks like this:

```
    let seen' = failwith "to be written" in
    let rest' = failwith "to be written" in 
    helper (seen',rest')
```

What it's saying is: calculate a new value for `seen` and a new value for `rest`, then call yourself recursively with the two new values.

Comment: So basically I call the helped function on ([],l) where seen starts out as empty and l is the entire list then it does pattern matching and recursion and at the end I want to return the list of elements backwards so I can do List.rev on it ? also Since seen starts as [] and rest is the entire list do I want seen to become every element that I saw that isnt duplicated and rest to become the empty list at the end of the function?

Comment: Something like that sounds right. Very often you don't have to try to accumulate the list backwards, it just happens that way. So the assignment is helping you by showing how to handle this. (It only adds a linear amount of time to reverse the list at the end.)

Comment: Since seen starts as [] and rest is the entire list do I want seen to become every element that I saw that isnt duplicated and rest to become the empty list at the end of the function?

Comment: Again this sounds very plausible. I don't want to solve your assignment for you :-)

Comment: yep i figured it out thanks for your help this worked                                                                                                  let removeDuplicates l = 
  let rec helper (seen,rest) = 
      match rest with 
        [] -> seen
      | h::t -> 
        let seen' = 
          if(List.mem h seen) then seen
          else (h::seen)  
        in
        let rest' =  t
      in
   helper (seen',rest') 
  in
      List.rev (helper ([],l))
    ;;